# SimpleDateFormat Exception with a perfect string

Tags: java, android, exception, simpledateformat

The following code gives me this exception:

```
PID: 8473                                                                
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid time, expecting HH:MM:SS format
```

What I am trying to do is to check if a given time is between two times.
I have managed to create a simple method but it went wrong when I am trying to check between lets say 20:00 - 04:00, so once it passed the 00:00 it was wrong, so I came here and found:

```
public static boolean isTimeBetweenTwoTime(String argStartTime,
                                           String argEndTime, String argCurrentTime) throws ParseException {
    String reg = "^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";
    //
    if (argStartTime.matches(reg) && argEndTime.matches(reg)
            && argCurrentTime.matches(reg)) {
        boolean valid = false;
        // Start Time
        java.util.Date startTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(argStartTime);
        Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCalendar.setTime(startTime);

        // Current Time
        java.util.Date currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(argCurrentTime);
        Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentCalendar.setTime(currentTime);

        // End Time
        java.util.Date endTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(argEndTime);
        Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCalendar.setTime(endTime);

        //
        if (currentTime.compareTo(endTime) < 0) {

            currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            currentTime = currentCalendar.getTime();

        }

        if (startTime.compareTo(endTime) < 0) {

            startCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            startTime = startCalendar.getTime();

        }
        //
        if (currentTime.before(startTime)) {

            System.out.println(" Time is Lesser ");

            valid = false;
        } else {

            if (currentTime.after(endTime)) {
                endCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                endTime = endCalendar.getTime();

            }

            System.out.println("Comparing , Start Time /n " + startTime);
            System.out.println("Comparing , End Time /n " + endTime);
            System.out
                    .println("Comparing , Current Time /n " + currentTime);

            if (currentTime.before(endTime)) {
                System.out.println("RESULT, Time lies b/w");
                valid = true;
            } else {
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("RESULT, Time does not lies b/w");
            }

        }
        return valid;

    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Not a valid time, expecting HH:MM:SS format");
    }

}
```

So now I take the hours and minutes with a given 00 for the seconds and pass it by the above method, however I get an exception that a `String` or all the `Strings` I have entered are not in the right format.

I gave it a try with:

```
String start = "12:00:00";
String end = "15:00:00";
String current = "14:00:00";
```

and it worked good but when I enter the vars in the way that I need to it doesn't work and the exception is delivered.

```
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int dayOfTheWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int fromHour = biz.getOpeningHours().get(dayOfTheWeek-1).getFromHour();
    int fromMinute = biz.getOpeningHours().get(dayOfTheWeek-1).getFromMinute();
    int toHour = biz.getOpeningHours().get(dayOfTheWeek-1).getToHour();
    int toMinute = biz.getOpeningHours().get(dayOfTheWeek-1).getToMinute();

boolean insideTime = false;
    try {

        String start = ""+adjustText(fromHour)+":"+adjustText(fromMinute)+":00";
        String end = ""+adjustText(toHour)+":"+adjustText(toMinute)+":00";
        String current = ""+adjustText(hour)+":"+""+adjustText(minute)+":00";

        //String start = "12:00:00";
        //String end = "15:00:00";
        //String current = "14:00:00";
        insideTime = isTimeBetweenTwoTime(start,end,current);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the `adjustText` method:

```
public String adjustText(int adjustTimeNumber){

    String a = "";
    if (adjustTimeNumber == 0) {
        a = ""+ adjustTimeNumber + "0";
    } else if (adjustTimeNumber > 0 && adjustTimeNumber < 10) {
        a = "0" + adjustTimeNumber;
    } else {
        a = adjustTimeNumber+"";
    }

    return a;

}
```

Please help I don't get it, the `strings` are perfect but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Please narrow down the issue and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid converting date objects into Strings, and then parsing the strings back to time objects, feels unneeded.

Try this:

```
// I assume your "time" object is called TimeObj, change it to the correct name in your implementation

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int dayOfTheWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
TimeObj t = biz.getOpeningHours().get(dayOfTheWeek-1);

Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
from.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, t.getFromHour());
from.set(Calender.MINUTE, t.getFromMinute());
from.set(Calender.SECOND, 0);

Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
to.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, t.getToHour());
to.set(Calender.MINUTE, t.getToMinute());
to.set(Calender.SECOND, 0);

if (from.after(to)) {
    // this means to "to" is after midnight, add a day to "to"
    to.set(DATE, to.get(DATE) + 1);
}

boolean insideTime = now.after(from) && now.before(to);
```

Comment: but what if the from time is 18:00 and the to time is 03:00 so its the next day and currentTime is 1:00 then insideTime will return false

Comment: i've added some more improvements, using `after` and `before` instead of `compareTo`, a lot more readable now.